# How to substitute piece of code after match is found | Linux |

Tags: linux, sed

I have a Scenario 
where their is a ABC.txt file

**In this ABC.txt file their is multiple HTML's available**

```
<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**After every end of** `</HTML>`

**I want to add my piece of code**

```
<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>
```

**Output should be like below**

```
<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>
```

Any other approach to do this is appreciated

Comment: It's impossible to parse html or xml using regular expressions with `sed`. You write `< /ABC>` with a space after `<`, is this intentional? Please post expected output you want to have with the lines replaced, for the sample input you provided. The second `</ABC>` should be replaced too? Should a line like `</ABC></ABC>` be replaced two times?

Comment: @KamilCuk => the space is coming < /ABC> that's because stackoverflow does not allow this kind of syntax that's why I have given space to show it .. where as it should not be space after '<

Comment: Ach ok. Just write it inside backticks \`. `</ABC>`

Comment: Do you only want to replace lines that contain exactly `</ABC>` and nothing else or do you want to replace `</ABC>` if it occurs in a line that contains other text, e.g. `foo</ABC>bar`? Do you want to have a search pattern that ignores some spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to escape so many characters. Spaces are not ignored, so if you put a space anywhere, it is going to be interpreted as a space in the input. Just:

```
sed 's%</ABC>%</HTML><HTML><BODY><br><br></BODY></HTML>%g'
```

will output for the input provided:

```
ABC
</HTML><HTML><BODY><br><br></BODY></HTML>
<RAM>
<VI>
</HTML><HTML><BODY><br><br></BODY></HTML>
```

The `/` nor `<` nor `>` are not special, there is no need in escaping them.

Comment: => Wounderfull Thanks man Code is perfect I have updated question will you see it this is my actual scenario any other approach then sed

Comment: (If you have GNU sed implementation) you then substitute  `</HTML>` with `\n\n</HTML><HTML><BODY>.....`. The `\n` is a newline. And please don't ask XY questions. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk '/<\/HTML>/ {$0=$0"\n\n<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>"} 1' file
<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>

<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TD><TR>NAME</TR><TD>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><BODY><br></br><br></br></BODY></HTML>
```